# brew link libgpg-error use libgpg-error-1.12 while I have libgpg-error-1.13 instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I use OS X 10.9.4.
I wanted to install ruby-2.1.1 by rvm install 2.1.1
But I got some error. I checked the log and found that I must `brew link libgpg-error` first before I install libksba, But, when I execute the command `brew link libgpg-error`, I got an error message says `Linking /usr/local/Cellar/libgpg-error/1.13... Error: No such file or directory - /usr/local/Cellar/libgpg-error/1.12/share/common-lisp`, I checked the comment there, and found here is only libgpg-error/1.13, not libgpg-error/1.12. And I searched in the google search engine, Nothing could I found.
So, How should I do to successfully execute `brew link libgpg-error`?

Comment: First install libgpg-error, `brew install libgpg-error` and check brew  `brew doctor`

Answer (score 1):

Had similar error, fixed by `brew prune`. Based on https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/32169